# How do I display two different CSV files in two QTableViews in a tabWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am able to load in and write to a CSV file into my QTableView, however, I want to be able to adapt this code to be able to do this for two different CSV files in two separate tableViews, withing two tabs of a QTabWidget.

```
import sys
import csv
import fileinput
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, fileName, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        MyWindow.setGeometry(self, 0,0,800,420)

        self.fileName = fileName

        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)

        self.tableView = QTableView(self)


        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)


        self.pushButtonLoad = QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonLoad.setText("Load Csv File!")
        self.pushButtonLoad.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonLoad_clicked)

        self.pushButtonWrite = QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonWrite.setText("Write Csv File!")
        self.pushButtonWrite.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonWrite_clicked)

        self.layoutVertical = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonLoad)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonWrite)

    def loadCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "r") as fileInput:                    
            for row in csv.reader(fileInput):
                items = [
                    QStandardItem(field)
                    for field in row
                ]
                self.model.appendRow(items)
                #self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

    def writeCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "w") as fileOutput:                   
            writer = csv.writer(fileOutput, lineterminator='\n')  
            print('rowCount->', self.model.rowCount())
            for rowNumber in range(self.model.rowCount()):

                fields = [
                    self.model.data(
                        self.model.index(rowNumber, columnNumber),
                        Qt.DisplayRole
                    )
                    for columnNumber in range(self.model.columnCount())
                ]
                print('fields->', fields)
                writer.writerow(fields)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonWrite_clicked(self):
        self.writeCsv(self.fileName)
        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonLoad_clicked(self):
        self.loadCsv(self.fileName)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow("C:\Qt\csv.csv")
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I know how to add the two table views to separate tab widgets, its just the methods for the load and write buttons to handle two separate csv files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you should have 2 widgets of the same type in each tab so creating a custom class is a good option. On the other hand it is better to get the CSV through a dialogue because if you want to load another file you would have to modify the code and the user should not do that. And finally I'll create a QMainWindow where the QTabWidget will be placed, and in each tab I'll set the custom widget.

```
import sys
import csv
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 420)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        self.pushButtonLoad = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Load Csv File!",
            clicked=self.on_pushButtonLoad_clicked)

        self.pushButtonWrite = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Write Csv File!",
            clicked=self.on_pushButtonWrite_clicked)

        layoutVertical = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layoutVertical.addWidget(self.tableView)
        layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonLoad)
        layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonWrite)

    def loadCsv(self, fileName):
        self.model.clear()
        with open(fileName, "r") as fileInput:                    
            for row in csv.reader(fileInput):
                items = [
                    QtGui.QStandardItem(field)
                    for field in row
                ]
                self.model.appendRow(items)

    def writeCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "w") as fileOutput:                   
            writer = csv.writer(fileOutput, lineterminator='\n')  
            print('rowCount->', self.model.rowCount())
            for rowNumber in range(self.model.rowCount()):
                fields = [
                    self.model.item(rowNumber, columnNumber).text()
                    for columnNumber in range(self.model.columnCount())
                ]
                print('fields->', fields)
                writer.writerow(fields)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonWrite_clicked(self):
        fileName, _ =  QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, self.tr("Open CSV"), 
            QtCore.QDir.currentPath(), self.tr("CSV Files (*.csv)"))
        if fileName:
            self.writeCsv(fileName)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonLoad_clicked(self):
        fileName, _ =  QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, self.tr("Open CSV"), 
            QtCore.QDir.currentPath(), self.tr("CSV Files (*.csv)"))
        if fileName:
            self.loadCsv(fileName)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        tabwidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(tabwidget)
        tabwidget.addTab(Widget(), "tab1")
        tabwidget.addTab(Widget(), "tab2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!